# Jekyll is not reading site.posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Recently, I decided to start my Blog on Github Pages. I forked **Jekyll-Now** and pulled the code into my local environment.

Now I am running `jekyll serve` but it is not reading the posts in the _posts folder!.

It seems that the `site.posts` variable in `index.html` couldn't be read. If I output the variable or inspect it as : `{{ site.posts | inspect }}` then it is empty.

The posts names are within the correct format YYYY-MM-DD-TITLE.md
If I run `jekyll serve` inside the `_posts` folder, then I will get an `IndexOf` page with all the posts listed without any problem.

The content of `_config.yml` :

```
# Name of your site (displayed in the header)
name: My name

# Short bio or description (displayed in the header)
description: Blog on various topics

# URL of your avatar or profile pic (you could use your GitHub profile pic)
# avatar: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/master/images/jekyll-logo.png

# Includes an icon in the footer for each username you enter
footer-links:
  github: motleis/blog

baseurl: ""
permalink: /:title/

# The release of Jekyll Now that you're using
version: v3.4.0

# Jekyll 3 now only supports Kramdown for Markdown
kramdown:
  # Use GitHub flavored markdown, including triple backtick fenced code blocks
  input: GFM
  # Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    # Use existing pygments syntax highlighting css
    css_class: 'highlight'

# Set the Sass partials directory, as we're using @imports
sass:
  style: :expanded # You might prefer to minify using :compressed

# Use the following plug-ins
gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap # Create a sitemap using the official Jekyll sitemap gem
  - jekyll-feed # Create an Atom feed using the official Jekyll feed gem

# Exclude these files from your production _site
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - LICENSE
  - README.md
  - CNAME
```

Under _posts: I have only simple sample file :
2014-3-3-Hello-World.md

```
---
layout: post
title: You're up and running!
---

Just a single line that should be displayed!
```

And here goes the content of `index.html`, where the posts should be listed:

```
site.posts : {{ site.posts }}
My posts:
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      {{ post.excerpt }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The result is :

```
site.posts :
My Posts:
```

As you can see site.posts is empty!

What is your suggestions to debug this issue?

I am running jeykll-3.4.0

Comment: Post the post you located in the `_posts` folder and its filename. Also `_config.yml`.

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy for your comment and for editing the markups in my question. I just edited the post and hope it is more clear

Comment: Seems to be fine, it should work with `jekyll serve` at the root folder (i.e. the folder that contains `_config.yml`)

Comment: Indeed, I am running `jekyll serve` at the root folder where the `_config.yml` and `_posts` folder are located. `Index.html` is also located there, and it seems to be compiled fine into `_site` folder. If I edit the `index.html` with a static content, it will be built fine. The problem is that the variables are not accessed for some reason.

Comment: The filename was it: `YYYY-MM-DD-TITLE.md` is different than `2014-3-3-Hello-World.md`

Comment: Better help if you give a repository url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Answer:

Check that your posts are in YYYY-MM-DD-title.MARKUP, i.e. 2017-**0**1-**0**1-title.md style, with 0 for padding.

Under "Creating Post Files" in ["Writing Posts"](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) on Jekyll's documentation page:

> To create a new post, all you need to do is create a file in the _posts directory. How you name files in this folder is important. Jekyll requires blog post files to be named according to the following format:
>
> `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP`
>
> Where YEAR is a four-digit number, MONTH and DAY are both two-digit numbers, and MARKUP is the file extension representing the format used in the file. For example, the following are examples of valid post filenames:
>
> `2011-12-31-new-years-eve-is-awesome.md`
> `2012-09-12-how-to-write-a-blog.md`

---

Former Answer:

Is your _posts folder located in your website's root directory?

My main suggestion otherwise is to create a layout (in the layouts folder) specifically for showing your index (so make a normal webpage and copy and paste the current non-frontmatter content of your index.md file inside). It's my understanding that if it's not Liquid or Markdown, your code is shown as is, and not read / processed for building the website. Even if you have an entirely empty bottom half to your index.md page, to my understanding it should show your posts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, the `_posts` folder is located at the root directory. I will try creating a layout as you suggested.

Comment: In `_layouts` there is a `default.html` file. If I edit it, the static changes will be shown. So I guess the problem is that the variables are not read.

Comment: Can you share the default.html file? The method I described is how I do my own layout, so while I think it looks better to be able to insert it through the markdown file (as you were doing), it's the compromise I've done. So I'm pretty curious as to what might be going on with your files.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed! Perhaps you lose something by not having your posts in an unordered list? Check under "displaying an index of posts." https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

Comment: Thanks @jncmaguire, I used the code you mentioned in index.html. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: So they go into the real nitty-gritty (well, relatively) in the link I sent you under "Creating Post Files," but after seeing what you posted, what immediately jumps out to me is that your files aren't in the right format. You need to write "2014-03-03-Hello-World.md" (note the extra 0s).

Comment: Thanks jncmaguire! That is it. The weird thing is that is it working fine in github pages ! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I wonder if the Jekyll for github is slightly different. I'll amend my current answer though! I'm happy it worked out.

Comment: I was running into a similar issue, though my dates were in the right format. My problem was that I had created a test post but chose a date in the future accidentally. Looks like future dates are ignored! Good to know...