# RSS feed.xml in Jekyll generates only one line

Tags: ruby, markdown, rss, jekyll

I tried to set up an RSS feed using Jekyll, and it worked
However, it does not generate the posts. I can only see this: (image is attached) How can I add my MD files of content?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>{{ site.title | xml_escape }}</title>
        <description>{{ site.description | xml_escape }}</description>
        <link>{{ site.url }}/</link>
        <atom:link href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.url }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <pubDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Jekyll v{{ jekyll.version }}</generator>
        {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
        <item>
            <title>{{ post.title | xml_escape }}</title>
            <description>{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</description>
            <pubDate>{{ post.date | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
            <link>{{ post.url | prepend: site.url }}</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ post.url | prepend: site.url }}</guid>
            {% for tag in post.tags %}
            <category>{{ tag | xml_escape }}</category>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for tag in page.tags %}
            <category>{{ cat | xml_escape }}</category>
            {% endfor %}
        </item>
        {% endfor %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

this is what I see

[image]

Comment: Seems like the `site.posts` collection is empty.

Comment: so maybe it's not the right name? because i have a lot of md posts, so any tip on what to do?

Comment: There seem to be various reasons, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42533288/477037 https://stackoverflow.com/q/63405212/477037 https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579731/477037

Comment: I didnt find the solution for my problem, I saw that I have pages directory, maybe this is the problem? that i need to change post to "page"?

Answer (score 0):

I changed post to page and it seems to work, but i don't see the title